# Cant Push data to Firebase - React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, redux

I'm trying to save user input data to firebase's realtime database. 
I'm not using authentication.
I just need my user input data to be fetched on firebase data fields in realtime database. 
I have a null database as of now.

But Im getting the following error when i click submit button to push data to firebase

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGtxb.png)

My action:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'; import {   TRIVIA_POST } from
> './types';
> 
> 
> export const triviaPost = ({ anss }) => {
> 
>   return (dispatch) => {
>     firebase.database().ref(`/answers`)
>       .push({ anss })
>       .then(() => {
>         dispatch({ type: TRIVIA_POST });
>       });   }; };
```

My Reducer:

```
import {
  TRIVIA_POST
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TRIVIA_POST:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Reducer Index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import SceoneReducer from './SceoneReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  triviaPost: TriviaReducer
});
```

My Answer Submit Screen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; import { View, Image, Span }
> from 'react-native'; import {   Container,   Header,   Title,  
> Content,   Button,   Footer,   FooterTab,   Text,   Body,   Left,  
> Right,   Icon } from 'native-base'; import axios from 'axios'; import
> Card from './Card'; import CardSection from './CardSection'; import
> Input from './Input'; import { connect } from 'react-redux'; import {
> triviaPost } from './actions';
> 
> 
> class Trivia extends Component {   state = { trivia: [], time:[] };
> 
>     componentWillMount() {
>       axios.get("firebase_link")
>            .then(response => this.setState({trivia: response.data}));
>     }
>     onButtonPress() {
>         const { anss } = this.props;
> 
>         this.props.triviaPost({ anss });
>       }   render() {
>     return (
>       <Container>
>         <Header>
>           <Left>
>             <Button transparent onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}>
>               <Icon name="arrow-back" />
>             </Button>
>           </Left>
>           <Body>
>             <Title>Trivia Time</Title>
>           </Body>
>           <Right />
>         </Header>
>         <Card> <CardSection>
>         <Image style={{ height: 200, width: null, flex: 1 }} source = {{ uri: this.state.trivia.tq }} /> </CardSection>
>         </Card>
>         <View style={{width: null, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'white'}} />
>         <Card> <CardSection>
>         <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, flex: 1 }}>The Upcoming Trivia Time is @ {this.state.trivia.time} IST</Text> </CardSection>
>         </Card>
>         <View style={{width: null, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'white'}} />
>         <Card>
>         <CardSection>
>           <Input
>             label="Answer"
>             placeholder="Enter Answer"
>             value={this.props.anss}
>           />
>         </CardSection>
>         <View style={{width: null, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'white'}} />
>         <Footer>
>           <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
>             <Text>Submit Answer</Text>
>           </Button>
>         </Footer>
>         </Card>
>       </Container>
>     );   } }
> 
> export default connect(null, { triviaPost })(Trivia);
```

Kindly help me 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you called firebase.initialize with the config object the initial config object on the top component?

Comment: I have done it in the root component of My React Native Project

Comment: Please, could you debug your code inside the function `onButtonPress` and check the actual value for the variable `anss`? By the error message, it seams that it is `undefined`.